# Problems at imgur?

Tags: support, images

A [question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2047672/19341) seems to have problem with some images I put.

Is this a temporary thing or do I have to do something?

Comment: See Meta Stack Exchange: [Intermittent Failed to upload image; imgur is rejecting the request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291609).

Comment: @arjafi ok so old question are also affected...

Comment: Basically everything served by imgur (I've had problems with my own avatar, for example). And this won't be limited to SE.

Comment: It is down, apparently because of the current an outage on Amazon S3.

Comment: @arjafi but this question doesn't seem to be affected: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2110660/relation-between-iharas-zeta-and-any-knot-polynomial

Comment: oh one pic is back now...

Comment: at least I found an answer to ["Why should I ![enter image description here][1]?"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8354/19341)